# Python inserting a new line character in string after delimiter

Tags: python, string, split

So I'm trying to insert a new line character after a delimiter is found in a paragraph.

```
for index, char in enumerate(lines_of_text):
    if char == period or char == question_mark or char == exclamation_mark:
        lines_of_text = lines_of_text[:index+1] + '\n' +        lines_of_text[index+1:]
```

The problem is is that it ends up printing something like this:

something!

ust!

! d

e! ab

t!

I assume the problem is something to do the string length having 2 chars added to it with every '/n'?

But I haven't been able to think of a way around it.

Comment: Yes, you are modifying something as you iterate over it. Try building a new structure instead.

Comment: You can use replace `your_string.replace('!', '!\n')`